# How can I fix indentation Error?When I am going to fill colors

Tags: python, indentation

I'm a beginner in Python,

I have this error :

```
unindent does not match any outer indentation level (<unknown>, line 24)
```

This is my code  :

```
import pygame

#get screen
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))

#Set title and logo
pygame.display.set_caption('Space Invaders')
icon = pygame.image.load('spaceship.png')
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)


#Running
running = True
while running:
    import pygame

    for event in pygame.event.get():

        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

  screen.fill((155 , 0, 0))
  pygame.display.update()
```

I tried to fill screen with colors, but above Error appears always.
Please help me to fix this.

Comment: You should tag this for Python and delete most of the other tags

Answer (score 0):

You have an indentation error in line 1, but I guess that's an error from pasting into Stack Overflow, as it isn't the source of your error message.

As the error message says, you are unindenting the lines:

```
  screen.fill((155 , 0, 0))
  pygame.display.update()
```

as they do not match the indentation of the `for` above them, nor have you unindented them enough to match the `while` above, so Python doesn't know where they belong. Ideally all indentations should be either 0 or a multiple of 4 spaces long.

The indentation of the last two lines should presumably be the same as the for loop above it. Also you only need to import pygame once so you shouldn't include that in the loop.

So (assuming you want those two lines inside the `while`) something like:

```py
import pygame

#get screen
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))

#Set title and logo
pygame.display.set_caption('Space Invaders')
icon = pygame.image.load('spaceship.png')
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)

#Running
running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():

        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    screen.fill((155 , 0, 0))
    pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 0):

Im guessing that your following a youtube pygame tutorial and got a bit lost when coping the exact same thing the creator was doing. I see that the screen.fill((155,0,0) is under the while wich is like it should be but i only see a spacing of 2. Im guessing that instead of pressing tab you simply put a spacing of 2 with the space bar. so simply press tab to align it correctly. this is a very simple mistake and python is a very sapcing sensitive langauge.